# C++11 multi threaded producer/consumer program hangs

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am new to C++11 and using threading features. In the following program, the main thread starts 9 worker threads and pushes data into a queue and then goes to wait for thread termination. I see that the worker threads don't get woken up and the program just hangs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::mutex _rmtx;
std::mutex _wmtx;
std::queue<unsigned long long> dataq;
std::condition_variable _rcv;
std::condition_variable _wcv;
std::atomic_bool termthd;

void thdfunc(const int& num)
{
    std::cout << "starting thread#" << num << std::endl;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> rul(_rmtx);
    while (true) {
        while(!_rcv.wait_until(rul, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 10ms, [] {return !dataq.empty() || termthd.load(); }));
        if (termthd.load()) {
            std::terminate();
        }
        std::cout<<"thd#" << num << " : " << dataq.front() <<std::endl;
        dataq.pop();
        _wcv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread*> thdvec;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wul(_rmtx);
    unsigned long long data = 0ULL;
    termthd.store(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        thdvec.push_back(new std::thread(thdfunc, i));
    }

    for ( data = 0ULL; data < 2ULL; data++) {
        _wcv.wait_until(wul, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 10ms, [&] {return data > 1000000ULL; });
        dataq.push(std::ref(data));
        _rcv.notify_one();
    }
    termthd.store(true);
    _rcv.notify_all();
    //std::this_thread::yield();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        thdvec[i]->join();
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out the problem. How can I make sure the threads get woken up and processes the requests and terminates normally?

Comment: Totally unrelated: `std::vector<std::thread*> thdvec;` could be `std::vector<std::thread> thdvec;` and then thdvec.emplace_back(thdfunc, i);` to construct the thread in place and `thdvec[i].join();` because it's not a pointer anymore. Fewer memory management issues than dynamic allocation with `new`

Comment: It looping in while (!_rcv.wait_until(rul, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 10ms, [] {return !dataq.empty() || termthd.load(); }));
If your dataq is empty, it will be looping forever, and cause you only push 2 items on dataq but you have 9 threads for poping it.

Answer (score 2):

This  `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wul(_rmtx);` will lock the `_rmtx` mutex until the end of main scope. It's surely an issue, because other threads trying to get the lock on `_rmtx` will block:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread*> thdvec;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> wul(_rmtx); // <- locking mutex until end of main. 
    // other threads trying to lock _rmtx will block

    unsigned long long data = 0ULL;
    // ... rest of the code ...
```

Comment: Thanks StPiere! That was indeed the problem

Comment: @sedu since that seems to have been the answer to your problem, mark this answer as correct so future askers can see that the problem was successfully resolved. This makes it more likely that the future askers will click on the question and learn from it.